# jquery won't fire - alert raised on script to call plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have the jquery script that I am attempting to run.

It is to download into excel file, data from a html table.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html

When I try and run the button, it brings up an error stating within this call script:

```
<script>
$(".dataTable_wrapper button").click(function(){
  $("#table2excel").table2excel({
    // exclude CSS class
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Excel Document Name"
  }); 
});
</script>
```

The error happens on the 2nd line: 
"Uncaught type error: $(....) table2excel is not a function"

Comment: Did you include the `jquery.table2excel.js` file on your page?

Answer (score 2):

You may be importing the libraries in the wrong order. Try importing jquery before you import any jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Are you linkiing the js plugin properly? before de exetucion of the code? 
try wrapping the function like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".dataTable_wrapper button").click(function(){
      $("#table2excel").table2excel({
        // exclude CSS class
        exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Excel Document Name"
      }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it depends, if he is linking the plugin below the code, it would be an issue

Comment: Why would it be an issue? `$("#table2excel").table2excel` is inside `click` event handler, so what is the chance that element is clicked before page is loaded?

Comment: well, chances are above 0, right? ;)
But yeah, it's probably what Phiroze said, importing them in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple after all that. I had my script with:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
```

When I changed the location to an actual URL ie:

```
<script src="myawesomesite.co.uk/wp-content/classes/assets/js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
```

Thanks for you support!